# Problem with creating a text channel in a acategory and some specific permissions

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i have a small problem with my code that at a given action must create a text channel in a category that is accessed by the server administrator, the user who invoked the command, and the user tagged in the command. It all works I manage to create the channel I can even add it to the right cateory but I can't change its permissions. I have tried a variety of methods including:
updateOverwrite
createOverwrite
overwritePermissions
updateOvermissions (Recommended by ChatGPT I think it was a bit gone when he recommended it)

The problem is that with all these methods I get back the error function not found

Any ideas?

Ecco il codice:

```js
guild.channels.create(
                {
                    name: "》《》" + user.user.username,
                    type: 0,
                })
                .then(channel => {
                    // set the parent category
                    channel.setParent({
                        id: "1067910662644314153"
                    });


                    channel.updateOvermissions([
                        {
                            id: user.user.id,
                            allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
                        },
                        {
                            id: author.id,
                            allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
                        }
                    ]);

                });
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: Discord js version: 14.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for you.
Try creating the channel and directly assign it the parent and permissions as in the code I left you below. Also by default it doesn't take category permissions so I also recommend you add deny permissions for everyone. Hope that helped you out

```js
let everyoneRole = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === '@everyone');


            guild.channels.create(
                {
                    name: "》《》" + user.user.username,
                    type: 0,
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: user.user.id,
                            allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages]
                        },
                        {
                            id: author.id,
                            allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages]
                        },
                        {
                            id: everyoneRole.id,
                            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages]

                        }
                    ],
                    parent: "1067910662644314153"
                })
```